# How can I make Tableau iframes printer friendly?

Tags: iframe, printing, tableau-api

Tableau allows the user to embedd visualizations via `iframe` ([source](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/embedding-tableau-public-views-in-iframes)). But when I try to print a web page with such a visualization via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Chrome it just shows an horizontal scroll bar.

Right now, I don't know how to investigate that problem. Do you have any idea what could cause it?

### The problem

The stylesheets in the embedded iframes contain `media="screen"`. Simply removing it makes the plot to appear at least. While the looks could be improved, it is usable.

### :toolbar=yes / top

The toolbar (see [docs](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_list.html)) looks like this:

[image]

While that might be a possible step, I see several problems:

- It contains too much unncessary information. I only want the download option ("Herunterladen"), but I get 9 more buttons. Can I customize them?
- One page contains multiple charts. The user should not be forced to manually download all of them when he wants to print the page.

Comment: You can try showing the toolbar in you embedded viz (:toolbar=yes), that will give you Tableau's Export feature. The export to PDF option is printer friendly since it lets users select scaling and page size. Disadvantage: It is a multi-step process, first users export a 'printer-friendly' PDF and then they print it. Advantage: you don't have to do much :)

Comment: @merawalaid Thank you for your comment! I had a look at it and the exported PDF looks nice. But I still would prefer it if the normal PDF print would work. Also: Do you know if the toolbar can be customized?

Comment: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_export_to_pdf.html could also be interesting.

Comment: And [Enable printing of Tableau charts embedded in a web page](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1348) mentions that `media="screen"`  should be removed from the CSS links. How can one do this for an iframe?

Comment: I don't think the toolbar can be customized beyond it position (top/bottom) and hiding share controls